# How to set data in columns accordingly in excel sheet

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, activereports

I have a active report that i have to export in excel sheet.When i am exporting that active report into excel sheet, columns being shifted.
I am writing this following code for exporting in excel sheet.

```
txtFilename.Text = doc.Name + ".xls";
                    this.export = new XlsExport();

                    DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Export.Xls.XlsExport docexp = new DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Export.Xls.XlsExport();
                    docexp.DisplayGridLines = true;
                    docexp.FileFormat = FileFormat.Xls95;
                    docexp.FileFormat = FileFormat.Xls97Plus;//or Xls97Plus
                    docexp.MinColumnWidth = 660;
                    docexp.MinRowHeight = 250;
                    docexp.MultiSheet = true;
                    docexp.RemoveVerticalSpace = true;
                    docexp.UseCellMerging = true;
```

How can I realign and resize the column headers and the detail columns in excel sheet?

Comment: its a predefine class in activereport.Export.Xls.XlsExport dll

Answer (score 0):

The columns in the excel sheet are calculated based on the left and right coordinate of every textbox or other control in the sheet. So the only real way to influence the columns in the excel sheet is to very carefully make sure that all the textboxes or other items in the report are precisely aligned - especially their left/x position.